# Loop infinito con promesa

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo serías dudas acerca de esto que me surgió hace poco.

Quiero hacer un loop infinito de un request a una API cada 15 segundos, pero quiero que el loop espere la respuesta de la promesa y luego pasen otra vez 15 segundos.

**Entonces, el comportamiento que busco es algo parecido a esto:**

```
Request -> (Tiempo aleatorio) -> Repuesta -> (Espera 15 seg) 
-> Request (Comenzando el ciclo nuevamente).
```

**Y lo que consigo es...**

```
Request -> (Tiempo aleatorio) -> Repuesta -> (Espera 15 seg) 
-> Request -> (Tiempo superior a 15 segundos) (Request)...
```

Hace un request sin esperar que la promesa anterior se haya cumplido, ese es el problema.

**Código de ejemplo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/nlbi21/gsz944pg/18/

Si me pueden echar una mano sería de mucha ayuda.

Gracias a todos.

Comment: ¿No sería mejor ir por el lado de ver aplicaciones en tiempo real? Digo, conociendo que estás con NodeJS, http://Socket.io sería una buena opción. Saludos

Comment: Hola @fredyfx, si si estamos usando Socket.io pero el request se hace cada 15 segundos a una base de datos relacional. Entonces después que recibo esa información envió la misma hacia todos los clientes necesarios por socket.io. La idea es hacer un solo request. Saludos y gracias, si se te ocurre algo mejor por favor no dudes en decirme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar una función (asíncrona) recursiva.

Primero, ya que vamos a utilizar promesas, vamos a realizar un par de funciones que nos faciliten el trabajo:

```
// Se resulve una vez haya pasado el tiempo de espera
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

// Utilizamos fetch para hacer una llamada a la API
const apiCall = url => fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
```

Finalmente creamos la función que estará continuamente llamándose a sí misma:

```
async function infiniteApiCalls(url, ms) {
  // Request (Tiempo Aleatorio)
  const result = await apiCall(url)
  // Haz lo que sea con el resultado
  console.log(result)
  // ...
  // Esperar x segundos
  await delay(ms)
  // Request otra vez
  await infiniteApiCalls(url, ms)
}
```

**EJEMPLO**

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms))

const apiCall = url => fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())
  // Si no quieres que el loop se pare
  // si hay un error, captura el catch
  // o utilizar try/catch en la función
  .catch(() => 'Error :/')

async function infiniteApiCalls(url, ms) {
  // Request (Tiempo Aleatorio)
  const result = await apiCall(url)
  // Haz lo que sea con el resultado
  console.log(result)
  // ...
  // Esperar x segundos
  await delay(ms)
  
  // Request otra vez
  //infiniteApiCalls(url, ms)

  const fn = infiniteApiCalls.bind(null, url, ms)
  
  setTimeout(fn, 0)
}

infiniteApiCalls('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', 15000)
```

Comment: Hola Jose gracias por responder, tengo una duda ¿que pasa si el request de la API tarda mas de 15 segundos? ¿vuelve a hacer otro request?. Saludos y gracias nuevamente.

Comment: De nada! Si tarda más de 15 segundos no hace otra llamada, el uso de await hace que no ejecute la siguiente instrucción hasta que se resuelva la promesa(hasta que la llamada tenga éxito o fracaso) de igual forma que pasa con `await delay(ms)`

Comment: Una duda que me ha surgido: al ser algo recursivo, ¿no se irían acumulando las llamadas de tal manera que cause un desbordamiento de pila? Parece que la primera llamada a `infiniteApiCalls` no terminaría nunca, al llamarse a sí misma ...

Comment: Pues supongo que sí, @PabloLozano, ayudaría utilizar un setTimeout como en la edición?

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba, poniendo los tiempos de espera a 0 y, efectivamente las llamadas se anidan... pero tras un minuto y cientos de llamadas aún no ha fallado... así que supongo que esta solución es "usable"

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Sí, eso "saca" el flujo de la recursividad pura y no se anida

Comment: Hola muchachos de verdad me parece interesante la discusión ando aun con dudas acerca de esto, porque precisamente es lo que no quiero que se aniden. Ya que da problemas de performance, son demasiados llamados y no quisiera que en una se pise con al otra.

Comment: No termino de entender la linea  "infiniteApiCalls.bind(null ,url, ms)" del escript final.

Comment: Es para hacer el binding del contexto y los parámetros de la función sin ejecutarla. Esa función se ejecutará como callback del setTimeout.